# Node Js, javascript, mysql, what the client see/not see?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, node.js

I have to do a web application that must run on desktop browser and mobile for an university project. I have to do it with HTML/CSS/JavaScript/Node/MySQL.
I'm understanding now what node.js is and as I understood it's like an apache that response sending an HTTP packet when a client request something. I added Node Express too and I made the MySQL implementation.
Now I made a page with ejs extension that contains a for cycle and the value of a variable taken from the DB. Now, my questions are:
Who execute the for? (The client or the server)
The list/array of results of the MySQL query is sent to the client and then is the client to decide which of the row must be printed according of the JavaScript or the server make the HTML page and send it to the client directly?

This is the node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var select;
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "myPassword",
    database: "test"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT nome FROM prova", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      select = result;
    });
  });

app.get('/count/:number', function(req, res) {
  res.render('page.ejs', {counter: req.params.number, names: select});
});

app.listen(8081);
```

This is the page that I requests:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Titolo pagina web</title>
    </head>
    <body><h1>Sto per contare fino a <%= counter %></h1>

    <p><% 
        for (var i = 1; i <= counter; ++i) {
    %>

    <%= i %> ...

    <% } %></p>

    <p>Bene, ho finito. Adesso scelgo un nome a caso tra quelli che mi sono stati inviati.
        <%= names[0].nome %>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[EJS](https://ejs.co/), is a [templating engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor).

[image].

> The list/array of results of the MySQL query is sent to the client and then is the client to decide which of the row must be printed according of the JavaScript or the server make the HTML page and send it to the client directly?

No. The client receives the processed data already, he can't see the source designed on the template neither the NodeJS source code.
A simple analogy is looking at templates as if they where a college application, hundreds of students will receive the same form, you just have to fill the blanks and then send. Whoever reads the application won't know HOW you wrote, wich pencil you used, the time you did, they'll just see the data already processed.
The server will process the data and send the result as plain HTML in your case.

Comment: So, is it server side like a php page?

Comment: @davidelavalle Yes. The behavior is the same as Blade on Laravel for example.